# Not able to send the pander table intact in Gmail using sendmailR

Tags: r, pander, sendmailr

Please find below my code that I am using to share my analysis (dataframe) with my friend in R. I am using *sendmailR* package and *pander*:

```
library(sendmailR)

from <- "<me@gmail.com>"
to <- "<friend@gmail.com>"
subject <- "Important Report of the Day!!"
body <- "This is the result of the test:"                     
mailControl=list(smtpServer="ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.COM")
#-----------------------------------------------------
msg_content <- mime_part(paste('<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0
Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
</head>
<body><pre>', paste(pander_return(pander(vvv, style="multiline")), collapse = '\n'), '</pre></body>
</html>'))

msg_content[["headers"]][["Content-Type"]] <- "text/html"

sendmail(from=from,to=to,subject=subject,msg=msg_content,control=mailControl)
```

Problem is that in the mail the table is broken into two parts (8 column table and 4 column table) PFB the sample picture

[image]

How do I change my code so that my table of 12 columns remain intact.

After adding this line

```
panderOptions('table.split.table', Inf)
```

This is the email that I am getting [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3o4eb.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to increase or disable the [default max width of the resulting markdown table](http://rapporter.github.io/pander/#table-and-cell-width) via the `split.tables` argument of `pandoc.table` (that can be also used with the `pander` call, which will pass that argument to `pandoc.table` after all) or update the [global options](http://rapporter.github.io/pander/#general-options) via `panderOptions`.

Quick example on updating your `pander` call:

```
paste(pander_return(pander(vvv, split.tables = Inf)), collapse = '\n')
```

Or set that globally for all future `pander` calls:

```
panderOptions('table.split.table', Inf)
```

Comment: Thanks for replying. I got the table intact but it got screwed. Multiple columns are getting merged. How can I get them fit by altering their  size and column auto fit.

Comment: @AkshitR that's why we have a sane default not to print tables with more than 80 characters just like on the good old VT100 terminals :) But besides joking, that will depend on how your browser/e-mail client renders the wide `<pre>` tag. I think you want to add a HTML table to that e-mail instead of a verbatim markdown table -- look at eg `xtable` to generate HTML instead of markdown with `pander` (and I'm suggesting that despite the fact that I'm well committed to the latter package).